# Best approach to interface (abstract classes) design?

Tags: c++, error-handling, abstract-class

I've searched on this topic but couldn't really find a relevant answer...

Suppose I have an abstract class declared like this :

```
class Abstract{

    virtual Interface* createHandle() = 0;

    virtual ~Abstract() = 0;
};
```

Basically, an abstract class that provides a unique function that returns any implementation of the class Interface (also an abstract class).

I'm wondering how can error be handled with such design. If `createHandle()` encounters an error and cannot return a pointer to an implementation of Interface, what's the best way to handle and notify this properly ?

The first thing that came to my mind was to return a null pointer, and then check in the calling code if the returned pointer was null. It would work, but I find this quite poorly designed, because the interface (namely Abstract) never implies that createHandle() can return a null pointer, or *will* return a null pointer to signal an error (and I find quite bad the fact of just leaving a comment saying "should return null if error").

Then, I thought of carrying this information in the Interface pointer. That is, adding two  public non-virtual function to the class that set/get some sort of error code. But I don't like it at all as it has nothing to do with the Interface class, but with the implementation of `createHandle()` which Interface has no knowledge about (i.e. having a member variable that stores errors related to the code *using* this class, which feels very wrong in my opinion, though I may be wrong).

I wonder then, what would be an elegant way of specifying how this function will behave in case of an error (in a way completely independent of any implementation, quite the other way around in fact : forcing implementations to deal with error the way it's been specified).

Comment: How about throwing an error in case of an error?

Comment: Just a side note, the destructor should be `virtual ~Abstract() = 0 { };` and `protected`.

Comment: @zenpoy, we throw exceptions, not errors ;)

Comment: @Moo-Juice: Can you explain why protected is desirable for dtor??

Comment: @Moo-Juice Indeed, the virtual dtor should have an empty body (I omitted it because I'm quite lazy and that wasn't the point but you're right). About the protected part, though, I don't know.

Comment: @Moo-Juice: I know, I also usually throw exceptions. I was just curious about throwing errors. :)

Comment: @nogard, actually - it was a mistake on my behalf.  You only really need a protected destructor if you plan on doing a `delete this;` at some point (e.g. an `IUNknown` implementation).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can throw an `exception` if the case is exceptional an must be handled (though you can not enforce this, but at least mark the situation exceptional). Otherwise returning `nullptr` is totally ok.

For example if you want to read a file that potentially may not exist - it's not a program error, it is an expected situation, so returning `nullptr` for a FileReader for example makes sence.

Also to indicate that `nullptr` is a valid think and to enforce checking you may return `boost::Optional` or your own optional class which may also contain error code.

Comment: The example with the FileReader is totally understandable, because we are used to these situation (as programers) and know that if the file does not exist, we may very well get a null value returned by anything that tries to open it/read it. But when this is about something completely different and potentially abstract for computers (like say, a bank account or anything), I think we can't make these kind of assumptions anymore. That's why I don't really feel at ease with this kind of approach.

Comment: @JBL: I differentiate two situations: 1. Expected fail (file does not exists) 2. Unexpected (new returned nullptr). For first case I prefere using `error codes`, for second - `exceptions`

Comment: I thought of error codes too, but as the function must returns a pointer to an implementation, where does the error code ends up if it fails ?

Comment: @JBL: please, see my edit. Another option is to change function signature to 1. `ErrorCode createHandle(Interface **interface)` or 2. `Interface *createHandle(ErrorCode &errCode)`

Comment: Oh indeed, thanks for the explanation. I didn't think of that (though I used a lot the winapi which is full of this kind of constructs...).

Answer (score 2):

If you have exceptions turned on, then exceptions are an option.

Answer (score 1):

You can choose eigher throwing exception, or returning nullptr, but not both at the same time.

I would recommend throwing exception, since it tells the caller the exact reason of the problem, while null is silent.